# Show column according to parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a SQL script that shows a column based on a user parameter. I can't find an acceptable answer anywhere.

This is a simplified version of what I want to do (in OracleDB):

```
SELECT Table_car.purchase_date  AS PurchaseDate,
       Table_car.sale_date AS SaleDate,
       CASE WHEN :userinput <> 999 THEN (SELECT Table_car.car_brand FROM Table_car WHERE Table_car.car_brand = :userinput ) 
       ELSE (SELECT Table_car.car_brand FROM Table_car) 
       END AS CarBrand

FROM Table_car
```

The pseudo code of what I want could be

```
if(user_input = 999)
   show_all_values_of(Table_car.car_brand );
else
   show_only_some_values_of(Table_car.car_brand, user_input);
```

This is the expected result:

```
if user_input <> 999 (if is 1, for example)
| PurchaseDate | SaleDate   | CarBrand |
+--------------+------------+----------+
|  03/12/2018  | 09/10/2021 |    1     |
----------------------------------------
|  13/06/2011  | 20/11/2021 |    1     |
----------------------------------------
|  22/01/2020  | 09/12/2021 |    1     |
----------------------------------------

else (if user input is 999)
| PurchaseDate | SaleDate   | CarBrand |
+--------------+------------+----------+
|  03/12/2018  | 09/10/2021 |    1     |
----------------------------------------
|  13/06/2001  | 20/11/2021 |    5     |
----------------------------------------
|  22/01/2020  | 09/12/2021 |    1     |
----------------------------------------
|  03/12/2018  | 09/10/2021 |    3     |
----------------------------------------
|  13/06/2012  | 10/10/2020 |    9     |
----------------------------------------
|  22/01/2020  | 09/12/2020 |    2     |
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the logic into the `where` clause, with `or`; something like:

```
SELECT Table_car.purchase_date AS PurchaseDate,
       Table_car.sale_date AS SaleDate,
       Table_car.car_brand AS CarBrand
FROM   Table_car
WHERE  :userinput = 999 OR Table_car.car_brand = :userinput
```

If your column was nullable you might want additional logic to handle that in a particular way, but it doesn't look like this should be. And if you need other conditions in the `where`, remember to put parentheses around the logic above to make sure it's interpreted as you intend; i.e.

```
WHERE  (:userinput = 999 OR Table_car.car_brand = :userinput)
AND ... something else
```

As an aside, you might want to consider using table aliases to reduce the typing a bit.